# Alternatives to Windows 7 device ContainterIDs

Tags: c++, windows, wdk

How would I identify which devnodes belong to a single physical device in earlier version of windows?

EDIT:

The reason I would like to do this is because implementing an event system that broadcasts removal events when a device is removed would otherwise require said system to produce more events than necessary for something like an xbox controller (which has 3 interfaces and 2 devnodes). I can't find anything other than the ContainerID that I could use to establish correspondence between parts of what comprise a single entity.

I am looking for an alternative that would allow me to determine such a correspondence and allow my program to run on older versions of windows as well.

ANOTHER EDIT:

The ContainerID property is unreliable. I have found 2 entries for xbox 360 controllers with the same ContainerID, yet they correspond to different physical controllers.

I've solved this problem with the following, which works with devices that provide a serial number (e.g. xbox 360 controllers) as well as with those that do not (e.g. cheap, fake PS3 wired USB controllers):

```
Algorithm:

Find a matching HID device ID for a given USB device ID

input: usb_device_id as a string (e.g. "USB\VID_045E&PID_028E\00E102A")
output: The corresponding HID device ID string

HKEY usb_keys <- open_key("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\USB")
HKEY hid_keys <- open_key("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\HID")

HKEY device_key <- open_key("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\"+usb_device_id)

string prefix <- device_key.ParentIdPrefix

retry
for each key in usb_keys
    for each subkey in key
        if prefix occurrs in subkey.name
            prefix <- subkey.ParentIdPrefix
            goto retry
        endif
    endfor
endfor

for each key in hid_keys
    for each subkey in key
        if prefix occurrs in subkey.name
            return "HID\"+key.name+"\"+subkey.name
        endif
    endfor
endfor

return null
```

I've written this in pseudocode for brevity because the C++ version is quite long (although it uses only one loop instead of two and doesn't involve a goto). Note that `key.name` refers to the key's name and `subkey.ParentIdPrefix` means to use `RegGetValue` to obtain that property. The resulting device ID can be passed to `CM_Locate_DevNode`. Criticism is welcome, as I am not sure if this is actually as robust as I think it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can discover this relationship using the [`CM_Get_Parent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff538610%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.

Comment: That works for most gamepads and keyboards I've tested. Unfortunately, it only works when they are plugged in and fails for devices like the xbox 360 controllers, as they are arranged differently in the registry. I've noticed that it also fails for devices that provide serial numbers, which appear to have the same organization of keys.